# Laravel, cannot delete item from model

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have the following in `ImageController.php`:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $image = Image::find($id);
    $image->delete();
    return Response;
}
```

And in route/web.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Image;    
Route::resource('image', 'ImageController');
```

But when using Postman for Chrome to send a `DELETE` request to http://localhost:8000/image/5 (currently returns an image when using `GET`), the image isn't removed from the server.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT, error log:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/Users/sahandz/Documents/School/Singapore/CS3226/retellgram-master 2/backend/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: use App\Image; defined ?

Comment: Any errors? What's the response to the request?

Comment: Error log added to the question.

Comment: use App\Image; is done in the Imagecontroller file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve `TokenMismatchException`, you would need to do any of the following:

1. Along with your postman delete request, send the csrf token as `_token` in the request body or `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the request header
2. Change the delete request to a get request for deletion. All get requests are considered as reading requests in Laravel and so, CSRF token validation is not performed. Beware that this would disable CSRF protection for this route
3. In your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file, comment out the `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` line to remove CSRF validation. Beware that this would disable CSRF protection for all web routes

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

So, if I want to do alternative 1, do I write `X-CSRF-TOKEN` as a key or value in the header? If you look at the Postman UI, you see that in the header option there's a `key` and a `value` field. What do I write in each one?

Comment: `X-CSRF-TOKEN` would be key and you would need to setup a get route that spits out the value. Then copy paste that into the value for this request

Comment: Could you elaborate on "setup a get route that spits out the value"? I'm totally new to this.

Comment: just add a route like so: `Route::get('ping', function() { return csrf_token();});`. Then visit the route, copy the value and in your postman use this token for the header for testing your delete route